# Modifying a code

Tags: arduino-uno

I use this code to turn on/off a small 5v dc motor. How can I modify it so that the arduino writes the potentiometer value to the motor when it is in ON state ?

```
int speed = analogRead(pot) / 4;
ButtonState = !digitalRead(Switch);

if (ButtonState != lastButtonState)
{ 
     if (ButtonState == 1) 
     {
         if (motorstate == 1) 
         {
             motorstate = 0;
         } 
         else
         {
             motorstate = 1; 
         }
     } 
     lastButtonState = ButtonState; 
}

digitalWrite(enable, motorstate);
delay(20);
```

Comment: It depends on whether `enable` is a pin capable of PWM or `analogWrite(enable,speed)`.

Comment: yes it is. i tried removing the last output statement and replaced it with 
```
if (motorstate == 1) analogWrite ( enable , speed ); 
```
but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

(this is not an answer, but just a comment, used to use code alignment).

This sketch (which I aligned in your code) can be rewritten to

```
int speed = analogRead(pot) / 4;
ButtonState = !digitalRead(Switch);

if (ButtonState != lastButtonState)
{ 
     if (ButtonState == 1) 
     {
         motorstate = (motorstate == 1 ? 0 : 1);
     } 

     lastButtonState = ButtonState; 
}

digitalWrite(enable, motorstate);
delay(20);
```

I suggest the best way to proceed is to add print statements and use the serial monitor to check what values you get and see what you expect (which is not fully clear).

Comment: oh i just figured it out :D i used this statement analogWrite ( enable , motorstate*speed)